# Restricting Download Bandwidth on Linux Using 'tc' Filter for IP 0.0.0.0/0

Tags: networking, 20.04, downloads, download-speed, traffic

I want to restrict download bandwidth using tc. I am using the following commands:

> root@ubuntu:/home/jakob# tc qdisc add dev ens33 handle ffff: ingress

> root@ubuntu:/home/jakob# tc filter add dev ens33 parent ffff: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip src 10.0.0.92 police rate 4mbit burst 45k drop flowid :1

The bandwidth restriction doesn't work, and I download with the maximum available speed. Then, I tried the same commands, but instead of my specific IP address, I used 0.0.0.0/0:

> root@ubuntu:/home/jakob# tc qdisc add dev ens33 handle ffff: ingress

> root@ubuntu:/home/jakob# tc filter add dev ens33 parent ffff: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip src 0.0.0.0/0 police rate 4mbit burst 45k drop flowid :1

Now, this restriction is working. If I change the rate from 4mbit to, for example, 6mbit with burst 65k, it uses the maximum download speed again, no matter what IP I use.

To make it workable again, I have to delete both the qdisc and filter and create them again. Sometimes I even have to reboot my device. I tried to view my filters using 'tc filter show,' and there was no output.